# Sending object with an intent creates a new object?

Tags: android, object, android-intent, memory

It took me forever to figure this out, but I'm noticing that when I pass an object in as an Extra to an Intent (in my case, an object extending Parcelable), for whatever reason it creates a new object in memory as opposed to holding onto the same object reference.

Is there a way to get it to retain the reference?

Comment: Dont ever have a the same reference on objects on difference activities or else you will get memory leak.

Comment: The problem is that if I update the object in the second Activity, I want it to also be updated back in the first activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for whatever reason it creates a new object in memory as opposed to holding onto the same object reference

That depends on what you are doing with the `Intent`. If you are passing it as a parameter to your own method, or otherwise using it *purely* in-process (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`), it should not copy the extras.

However, my guess is that you are doing something like:

- `startActivity()` and its various flavors (e.g., `startActivityForResult()`)
- `startService()`
- `bindService()`
- `sendBroadcast()` called on a `Context`
- wrapping the `Intent` in a `PendingIntent` and using that `PendingIntent` somewhere (e.g., as part of a `Notification`)

In all of these cases, your `Intent` data is passed outside of your app's process to a central OS process. This requires the data to be copied. If relevant (e.g., the activity you are starting is one of your own), the `Intent` data is passed back from the central OS process to your process, making another copy in your process.
In these scenarios, the copying is unavoidable.

> The problem is that if I update the object in the second Activity, I want it to also be updated back in the first activity.

Either:

- Do not have separate activities here, or
- Do not pass the object by means of an `Intent` extra (e.g., have a central cache of model objects, and pass the ID of the model in an extra, so the other activity can pull the object from the cache)

Comment: In particular I am using `startActivityForResult()` and using `putExtra` to send the Parcelable object to the second Activity, where it can be updated. Do I just pass the object back using the return Intent and then re-set the object in `onActivityResult` in the first Activity?

Comment: @ArukaJ: "Do I just pass the object back using the return Intent and then re-set the object in onActivityResult in the first Activity?" -- that's another possibility, though it is not especially flexible, and so I am not a fan of it.

Comment: How do you do the central cache approach? A public static class of object references? Won't this possibly get destroyed (since I'd be unable to do things like saving/restoring instance state)

Comment: @ArukaJ: "A public static class of object references?" -- something along those lines, making sure that you cap how much memory is used (e.g., use `LRUCache`). "Won't this possibly get destroyed" -- sure. That's why it is called a cache. "I'd be unable to do things like saving/restoring instance state" -- instance state is only for in-flight data, like the contents of a partially-filled-in form. It is not a data persistence mechanism. Your cache needs to be backed by a file or database, and you need to be able to load from the backing store if the object is no longer in the cache.

Comment: I tried implementing the cache here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601499/how-to-use-lrucache-to-create-a-central-cache-of-object-references and it seems to resolve the issue! Whether it's implemented correctly is up for debate, but it seems to be working so far. Thanks.